# How to make a structure interface that return a response with status and json.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a interface which describes a response payload.

```js
export interface ObjectResponseInterface {
    status : HttpStatusCode,
    error : Boolean,
    response : any
}
```

I create a response object typed to `ObjectResponseInterface`, but I want make a structure that always return this obj, `objRes` and `res.status`, and `res.json(objRes.status)` as follows

```js
const objRes : ObjectResponseInterface = {
        status : HttpStatusCode.BAD_REQUEST,
        error : false,
        response : response
      }
        
res.status(objRes.status).json(objRes)
```

Is there a way to implement this response as a interface, maybe to extend Express?

Comment: Did you check the answer ? @AIJw

Answer (score 0):

If I miss something please correct me, please. I think you can make this with a generic approach.

For example

```
// Generic Definition
export interface ApiResponse<T> {
  // "httpStatus" have to return the status as a number
  // because res.status accepts a number as a parameter.
  status: number,  
  error: boolean,
  response: T
}


// Usage Examples

// Response as primitive type
const objRes: ApiResponse<string> = {
  status: httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
  error: false,
  response: 'Request gone wrong'
}

res.status(objRes.status).json(objRes)

// Response as custom type
export type CustomType = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const objRes: ApiResponse<CustomType> = {
  status: 200,
  error: false,
  response: { id: 1, name: 'test' }
}

res.status(objRes.status).json(objRes)
```